# OSX: shm_open returns ENAMETOOLONG

Tags: macos, file, shared-memory

I am trying atm to create a shared memory file for my process. The filename constists of several parts to identify the process the SHM belongs to and whats its content. An example would be:
`shm_pl_dev_system_25077`

I create all the files in a directory I created in `/tmp` where I have full write and read permissions.

So the complete Path would be:
`/tmp/pl_dev/shm_pl_dev_system_25077`

I create several files there, some fifo pipes and other stuff and also the shm. The only Problem I get is that `shm_open` will always return the `errno 63 (ENAMETOOLONG)`.

Can you tell me what the issue here is?

Here is the code:

```
        handle_ = ::shm_open(shm_name.get(), O_RDWR, 0755);
        if (handle_ == -1 && errno == ENOENT)
        {
            // SHM does not yet exists, so create it!
            handle_ = ::shm_open(shm_name.get(), O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0755);
            if (handle_ != -1) {
                created_ = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!silent_)
                {
                    log.error("Couldn't create the SHM (%d).", errno);
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. As it seems OSX is very limited in the filename of SHMs... The maximum length for a filename currently is 31 chars per section (see `PSHMNAMELENGTH` in `/usr/include/sys/posix_shm.h`)